Taking a Screenshot of the Desktop while program runs
I am trying to take a Screenshot of the Desktop (With Icons and all) while a different program is running in front of it.
The only current way I can think about solving this issue was to minimize all windows infront of the desktop - take the screenshot - and then turn back the windows to their original state.
I thought that maybe I could change the alpha value of my target program while it is open for my screenshot, and then proceed to do all the steps mentioned above. However I do not know a way of doing so.
import cv2 as cv
import pyautogui
import numpy as np
import time

pyautogui.hotkey('win', 'd')

time.sleep(1)

screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()

screenshot = cv.cvtColor(np.array(screenshot), cv.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

pyautogui.hotkey('win', 'd')

cv.imshow('Screenshot', screenshot)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()



and whats the problem here? Do you want to take a screenshot with the program on the desktop?

I would like to take a screenshot of the desktop without needing to do something like minimising other windows and programs. Essentially, if possible, a way to produce the same end result that my current code does (capture a screenshot of the desktop) but without being as disruptive (the opening and closing of windows) or otherwise interrupting anything else the user is doing at that moment.

what's the purpose of capturing the desktop while there are visible windows? why should this not be disruptive? are you planning to run this more than a few times?

It's for a personal project of mine - inspired by the likes of KinitoPET and Oneshot where the program interacts with you in ways that are not normally expected of a program to do.
